# Splitting a string info maximum number of equal substrings

Tags: c++, string

Given a string, what's the most optimized solution to find the maximum number of equal substrings? For example "aaaa" is composed of four equal substrings "a", or "abab" is composed of two "ab"s. But for something as "abcd" there isn't any substrings but "abcd" that when concatenated to itself would make up "abcd".

Checking all the possible substrings isn't a solution since the input can be a string of length 1 million.

Comment: can substrings be overlapped ??

Comment: What's about "abcab"?

Comment: In your case, you have to count letters. "aaaa" has four equal substrings "a". "abab" has two equal substrings "a" or "b" or "ab". But if you want the maximum number then you want the shortest strings. The shortest string consists of one letter

Comment: I think, that you yourself don't know what you want to achieve. It's absolutly not clear what the algorithm should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no given condition for the substrings, an optimized solution to find the maximum number of equal substrings is to count the shortest possible strings, letters. Create a map and count the letters of the string. Find the letter with the maximum number. That is your solution.

EDIT:

If the string must only consist of the substrings then the following code computes a solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using ull = unsigned long long;

int main() {
  std::string str = "abab";

  ull length = str.length();

  for (ull i = 1; (2 * i) <= str.length() && str.length() % i == 0; ++i) {
    bool found = true;
    for (ull j = 1; (j * i) < str.length(); ++j) {
      for (ull k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
        if(str[k] != str[k + j * i]) {
          found = false;
        }
      }
    }
    if(found) {
      length = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Maximal number: " << str.length() / length << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This algorithm checks if the head of the string is repeated and if the string only consists of repetitions of the head.

`i`-loop iterates over the length of the head,
`j`-loop iterates over each repetition,
`k`-loop iterates over each character in the substring

Comment: for "xxxz" it would return 3, but it must be 1!

Comment: Why? "Given a string, what's the most optimized solution to find the maximum number of equal substrings". The substring "x" is three times in "xxxz". Specify your conditions.

Comment: As mentioned in the title, the string must be split into equal substrings., meaning that all the characters must be considered and put into a substring. The question is what would be the maximum length of these substrings.

Comment: I thought, you are looking for the maximum number of substrings. The maximum length is you original string as in `aaaa`, the maximum length is 4 because your longest substring is `aaaa`.